# decimal? with Left outer join gets null reference in LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to do left outer join in LINQ for two `var`s but on selecting required coloumns, I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error where I want `Nullable decimal`.

```
    var FLS = (from ee in SumTillFYEnd 
                        join es in SumTillFYStart on ee.Account equals es.Account into temp
                        from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()                             
                        select new
                        {  
                            Account = ee.Account, // As of here it works
                            BeginDr = (t.DrStartCF == 0) ? (decimal?) null : t.DrStartCF // Here I get error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                        });
```

Some times SumTillFYEnd and some times SumTillFYStart becomes null. I want to join should work with default values, in case any one or both is null.

Comment: Replace `t.DrStartCF == 0` with `t == null`

Comment: LINQ always showa t as null

Comment: Can't you run the LINQ query as an `IQueryable` that, as a whole, will get translated into SQL?

Comment: In my case No, I am re-writting a long sql stored procedure to LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is attempting to cast `null` to `decimal?`. You cannot ever directly cast `null` to another type, nullable or not. That will always cause a `NullReferenceException`. What you want instead is `default`. In other words, replace:

```
(decimal?)null
```

With

```
default(decimal?)
```

Comment: Here t is null, that is why accessing t.DrStartCF gives me NullRef. I could not find the way why t is null

Comment: Actually you *can* cast `null` to any nullable type.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a default class.

The reason I am seeing is that decimal can not be null so it either needs to set for a default value either `0` or `decimal.MinValue`

So, you require to have default class for `SumTillFYStart` like

`var defaultSumTillFYStart = new SumTillFYStart { Account = string.Empty, DrStartCF =0};`

With above in context, then in your piece of code replace

`from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()`

with this

`from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultSumTillFYStart)`

I have a linqPad working written below but for different subset; I think it will help somebody:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Debtor> debtors = new List<Debtor>();
    List<SecurityHolding> holdings = new List<SecurityHolding>();

    //Initialize Debtor
    debtors.Add(new Debtor(){
        AccountId = "J1",
        OutstandingValue = 501.95M
    });

    debtors.Add(new Debtor(){
        AccountId = "J2",
        OutstandingValue = 75.68M
    });

    debtors.Add(new Debtor(){
        AccountId = "J3",
        OutstandingValue = 100.01M
    });

    //Initialize Security Holding
    holdings.Add(new SecurityHolding(){
        AccountId = "J2",
        SecurityHoldingValue = 100M
    });

    holdings.Add(new SecurityHolding(){
        AccountId = "J3",
        SecurityHoldingValue = 200M
    });


    var defaultHolding = new SecurityHolding { AccountId= string.Empty, SecurityHoldingValue = 0};

    var result = (from d in debtors
                   join p in holdings
                   on d.AccountId equals p.AccountId into temp
                   from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultHolding)
                   select new
                   {
                        AccountId = d.AccountId,
                        OutstandingValue = d.OutstandingValue,
                        HoldingValue = (decimal?)t.SecurityHoldingValue
                   });

    result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Debtor
{
    public string AccountId {get;set;}
    public decimal OutstandingValue {get;set;}
}

public class SecurityHolding
{
    public string AccountId {get;set;}
    public decimal SecurityHoldingValue {get;set;}
}
```

Here the output:

[image]